# mySQL table updates, but not fast enough for a select statement on the same page to access the updates - any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write some code that updates a mysql table, and then selects out of that same table in the same page.  However, I find that when I do the update query, then the select query, it does not recognize the changes.  If, however, I refresh the page, then it recognized the changes.

I first have an insert statement something like this

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO matches (uid, win) VALUES ($uid, $win)';

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . ' in ' . $query);
```

Then, just after this, I have a select statement like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM matches where uid = $uid";

$resultmain = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . ' in ' . $query);
```

Of course I simplified the queries but, that is the general idea - and what happens is: the select statement will not recognize the update that was run immediately before it.  However, if I reload the page, and the select statement runs again after some time, it does recognize the change.

I googled for this and was very surprised to not come across anything yet.  Is there any good way to force to wait until the mysql update query finished before selecting?  If not, I might just have to use javascript to automatically reload the page, but this sounds like a messy solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me crazy...

--Anthony

Comment: That should not happen. Maybe it’s a problem in your code, which you did not post?

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Maybe it’s a problem in your code, which you did not post?

Things that come to mine, which could be the problem:

The 2 queries are run on different connections to the MySQL database. And auto-commit is not enabled.

Thus, first query would send the update but not commit, the second query will query on old data, and only after the page finishes (/later on) the commit occurs.

I’m not quite sure if non-auto-commited changes will be commited or rolled back when a PHP script ends, but it should be a rollback. Thus a later commit would be needed in your code as well for this possible scenario to apply.

Comment: but wouldn't the second query hang in the instance of auto commit being disabled? because the first query would never release the lock on the row?

Comment: Hey, kissaki, you are right I had the ordering of some other queries that were interfering with this one messing things up.  I reordered it and now it recognizes it.  Thank you for your input as it put me on the right track.

Will not having this auto commit thing enabled potentially cause problems with this kind of design in the future?  I haven't heard of it before, but if it's something you think is worth researching and adding to my site I'd appreciate the hint :).

Comment: @Jaitsu: That depends on what strategy the DBS will use. Normally no. For most DBS there’s no limit to reading the db. A non-commited change will not be read, but the recent commited state. A lock-everything strategy would be very harmful for performance and concurrency. Only when 2 writes occur will be real strategies kick in, on how they are handled. (newer one dropped? overwritten? …)

Comment: @Anthony: Auto-commit is the easier way to go. Especially beginners will be better off with it. But if you want control over what data is commited (saved, thus live in the DB), you’ll want to disable it and commit manually. This will especially be the case if you will have to change data in multiple queries before you reach a stable overall-state which you want to commit. Typical example: transfer money from one account to another. You don’t want to remove money from one account and then something happens (conflict, crash …). You only want to commit the changes to the DB after both succeeded.

Comment: As this answer answered your question pretty much, and your question is solved, please consider marking it as the answer to your question and thus marking this question solved.